# pyTelegramBot API как сделать цикл показа нескольких видео через клавиатуру бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Ребята, помогите пенсионеру. Мне 64 и решил вспомнить молодость и начать программриовать на `Python`.Заитересовался ботами. И хочу реализовать бота для проведения теста гибкости.
Бот должен показать пользователю 5 видео-упражнений на гибкость.
Результаты теста будут записываться в гугл таблицу.
Как показать одно видео  и записать пользователя и дату в гуглтаблицу разобрался. В этом коде этого нет. А вот с показом второго и следующих видео по очереди  трудности.

После каждого видео пользователь выбирает, что у него получилось и нажимает одну из трех клавиш,
Затем кнопка `ДАЛЕЕ` и выводится новое упражнение.
Здесь пример кода, где пробую организовать цикл показа видео.Пишу код для первого цикла и затык.
Почему-то после нажатия `ДАЛЕЕ` ничего не происходит.
Понимаю, что кнопка `ДАЛЕЕ` не обрабатывается. Но как  ее обработать не пойму.
Понял, что `telebot` уже устарел. Но вроде не сложная для него задача.

```
import telebot
import time
from telebot import types #для работы клавиатуры
from datetime import datetime
import gspread
from telebot.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from settings import googlesheet_id, token,  googlesheet_cluc


bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler( commands = [ 'start', 'help' ])
def send_welcome(message ):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Привет, здесь можно пройти тест на гибкость. ')
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data= 'yes')
    key_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='no')
    keyboard.add(key_yes,key_no)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Готовы пройти тест на гибкость?', reply_markup=keyboard)



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        print('Вывести видео')
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Здесь будет видео 1')
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Достали до колен - 1, до щиколоток - 2, до пола - 3')
    elif call.data == 'no':
        print('Нажато Далее')
    else:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'https://www.')

    key_ball = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard= True)
    item_1 = types.KeyboardButton('1')
    item_2 = types.KeyboardButton('2')
    item_3 = types.KeyboardButton('3')
    key_ball.add(item_1,item_2,item_3)
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выберите 1, 2 или 3', reply_markup=key_ball)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):
    if message.text == '1':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы получили " + str(message.text)+ " баллов")
    elif message.text == '2':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы получили " + str(message.text) + " баллов")
    elif message.text == '3':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы получили " + str(message.text) + " баллов")

    key_continue = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item = types.KeyboardButton('ДАЛЕЕ')
    key_continue.add(item)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Для продолжения нажмите ДАЛЕЕ ", reply_markup=key_continue)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message2(message):
    if message.text == "ДАЛЕЕ":
        print('Показать видео 2')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Comment: Спасибо!!! Кажется, то что надо. Я как раз изучал register_next_step handler и этот пример очень в тему. Тестирую.